# How to test containers/divs in react-testing-library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

For example:

I want to test if my custom CSS logo will render. I am trying to avoid using 'data-testid' attribute (because is supposedly not recommended).

**Logo component:**

```
 const Logo = ({ size }) => (
  <div className={styles.logoContainer}>
    <span className={size === 'small' ? `${styles.oSmall}` : `${styles.oBig}`} />
    <span className={size === 'small' ? `${styles.lSmall}` : `${styles.lBig}`} />
    <span className={size === 'small' ? `${styles.xSmall}` : `${styles.xBig}`} />
  </div>
);
```

**Part of another component when 'Logo' component is rendered**
(I want to test it here if the logo component will render in this component):

```
 <Container>
   <a title="anchor title" href="http://www.olx.pl" className="rel">
      <Logo color="turquoise" size="small" />
   </a>
 </Container>
```

**Test**:

```
it('should render logo', () => {
   render(<ComponentWithLogo />);
   expect(
     screen.getByRole('link', { name: /anchor title/i })
    ).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

I guess that this is not best way to test if a logo will render, because just change the child of this anchor tag and the test will still pass. Would it be better to use *data-testid* (to a wrapping container) in this case? I've noticed that this problem occurs often (mostly when I want to test if a component container has been rendered). Is it really bad to use *data-testid* in such cases?

Comment: I think testId is a recommended way for you in this case since your logo is a visual element which cannot or hard to identify by text or title

Comment: While I agree that it's fine to use a `data-testid` in this situation, you could also consider adding an explicit role and aria-label to the Logo's `div`, e.g. `<div className={styles.logoContainer} role="img" aria-label="OLX Logo">`. This would improve accessibility and you could then use the role/aria-label to access the element instead.

Comment: @juliomalves You're right, I already figured out that I should add e.g. a banner role